# use of "chemmacros" package give errors when define a newcommand

Tags: macros, environments

I am using chemmacros package to write chemical symbols in my thesis. (I am using Easy Thesis template with book class).

I added these packages (as below) at the top of thesis.cls file

```
\RequirePackage{textcomp}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{paralist}
\RequirePackage[bahasam,english]{babel}    

\def\theauthor{\textbf{!INSERT AUTHOR!}}
\def\thetitle{\textbf{!TITLE!}}
\def\@mtsubmissionyear{\textbf{!YEAR!}}
\def\@mtsijil{\textbf{!DEGREE!}} 

\newcommand{\submissionyear}[1]{\def\@mtsubmissionyear{#1}}
\newcommand{\sijil}[1]{\def\@mtsijil{#1}}

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[scaled]{helvet}
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}
\RequirePackage{courier}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{lmvtt}
```

I defined newcommand `\makecoverandtitlepage` as below at the bottom of thesis.cls file. (I took this command from UMthesis.cls (https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/universiti-malaya-thesis))

```
\newcommand{\makecoverandtitlepage}{%
    \ignorespaces
    \changepage{-40mm}{-15mm}{15mm}{0em}{0em}{20mm}{0em}{0em}{0em}
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \SingleSpacing%
        \centering%
        \renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}%
        \fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\fontsize{15pt}{17pt}\selectfont%
        \MakeUppercase{\thetitle}\par%
        \vfill%
        \MakeUppercase{\theauthor}\par%
        \vfill%
        INSTITUTE OF POSTGRADUATE STUDIES\\%
        UNIVERSITY OF MALAYA\\%
        KUALA LUMPUR\par%
        \bigskip%
        \@mtsubmissionyear\par%
    \end{titlingpage}%
    {\SingleSpacing\centering\thispagestyle{empty}\setcounter{page}{1}%
        \fontsize{15pt}{17pt}\selectfont%
        \renewcommand\ttdefault{lmtt}%
        \MakeUppercase{\thetitle}\par%
        \vfill%
        {\MakeUppercase{\theauthor}\par}%
        \vfill%
        {THESIS SUBMITTED IN FULFILMENT\\%
            OF THE REQUIREMENTS\\%
            FOR THE DEGREE OF \MakeUppercase{\@mtsijil}\par}%
        \vfill%
        {INSTITUTE OF POSTGRADUATE STUDIES\\%
            UNIVERSITY OF MALAYA\\%
            KUALA LUMPUR}\\[1em]%
        \@mtsubmissionyear%\\[3em]%
        \par\clearpage}%
    \changepage{40mm}{15mm}{-15mm}{0em}{0em}{-20mm}{0em}{0em}{0em}%
    \renewcommand\ttdefault{lmvtt}%
}
```

When I execute I get error as shown in the picture below

[image]

I need some help to fix this error.

Comment: I can't see the connection to `chemmacros` here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\submissionyear}[1]{\def\@mtsubmissionyear{#1}}
\newcommand{\sijil}[1]{\def\@mtsijil{#1}}
\makeatother
```

because you want to use internal commands (with `@`).

Comment: thanks for your help. But unfortunately I still get same error. This time I get more errors even from TableOfContents.tex, like - (Missing $ inserted. \tableofcontents).

Comment: after some playing around, I placed this newcommand in package.tex file and almost all errors are fixed except 2 errors  (chemmacros.sty)

Comment: @Vijay I wonder why this answers the question – according to your question the code is placed inside a `cls` file, anyway, where @ already is a letter? It looks to me as if the definition of `\makecoverandtitlepage` is in the document – then *that* should be enclosed with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.